# I have an installation error while installing GAMS

Tags: optimization, cplex, gams-math

I am trying to install GAMS on my computer. However, I always have a runtime error class invalid.
I noticed that GAMS support intel-based x86 processors only, is this related?

I want to solve this error. I tried stopping the Windows Management Instrumentation but there is still a runtime error

Comment: I never had the installer fail. Contact GAMS support at support@gams.com.